# How to plot a individual geolocation map using CSV file having 2 rows of value ,lat and long iterate over each coordinate and save it in a file

Tags: python, csv, geolocation, mapping

I have a csv file with two rows of long and lat values as headings. Now I want to plot a map of each location one by one and would like to save it as an image or HTML file.

I can plot all locations in a single frame using all lat and long values from a csv file.
I'm using this YouTube video in the same way.

and I am also able to store it in a directory, but with all the locations and markers on it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAn8Lx0qrks

```
xy_table = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
xy_table.head()

| lat       | long   |
| --------- | ------ |
| lat 1     | long 1 |
| lat 2     | long 2 |

xy_table['coordinates'] = xy_table[['long', 'lat']].values.tolist()   
xy_table.head()

print(xy_table)

from shapely.geometry import Point
xy_table['coordinates'] = xy_table['coordinates'].apply(Point)
xy_table.head()
 
|  lat       | long   |coordinates     |
| ---------- | -------|--------------- |
|  lat 1     | long 1 |POINT (long lat)|     |
|  lat 2     | long 2 |POINT (long lat)|

print(xy_table[['coordinates']])

type(xy_table)

stations = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(xy_table, geometry = 'coordinates')
type(stations)


osm_map = folium.Map(location=[stations.lat.mean(), 
stations.long.mean()], zoom_start=12)

points = folium.features.GeoJson(stations.to_json())

osm_map.add_child(points)

osm_map.save('project-1.html')
osm_map
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: added my code please review and help me to solve it..